# Import data from a workbook in the same folder depending on a changing name

Tags: excel, vba, import

Each week there will be a workbook created where "w" is the week number.

When the current workbook is for week "31" I want data to be taken from the closed workbook from week "30".

I have this.

```
Sub Import_Data()

  Dim rng As Range
  Dim WB2 As Workbook
  Dim FName As String

  FName = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path + "w"
  Set WB2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FName)

  ThisWorkbook.ChampSpecific.Range("L3:O6").Value = WB2.Worksheets(1).Range("M3:P6").Value

  WB2.Close

End Sub
```

The macro will be run from a button in the week "31" workbook.

I imagine the code will work but I don't know what the syntax would be for the line `FName = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path + "w"` to pick up the week number before the current one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, just for the previous week, you need something like this:

```
"AIMS_Report_w" & Format((WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(Now) - 1), "00")
```

or even

```
"AIMS_Report_w" & WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(Now) - 1
```

if you do not need it formatted.

---

Otherwise, if you want to provide the name of the previous current report and to get the previous one from it, something like this would be useful:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function GeneratePreviousWeek(strCurrentWeek As String) As String

    Dim lngPrevious     As Long
    Dim strResult       As String

    lngPrevious = Right(strCurrentWeek, 2)
    lngPrevious = lngPrevious - 1

    strResult = Left(strCurrentWeek, Len(strCurrentWeek) - 2)

    GeneratePreviousWeek = strResult + Format(lngPrevious, "00")

End Function

Sub TestMe()

    Debug.Print GeneratePreviousWeek("AIMS_Report_w05")
    Debug.Print GeneratePreviousWeek("AIMS_Report_w15")

End Sub
```

This is what you get in the immediate window:

```
AIMS_Report_w04
AIMS_Report_w14
```

The `GeneratePreviousWeek`function takes the last two chars of the name of the report returns a string with `-1`. The following should be used:

- the format is always with a leading 0. E.g., `01`, `02`
- if you ask for previous of `01` it returns `00`. Otherwise, you should be careful, sometimes there can be `53` weeks in the year, thus you need to provide the year as well.
- You may try to throw an error for values above `53`